# Two instances of tomcat running with ssl

Tags: java, tomcat, exception, ssl

I have two instances of tomcat running on the same VM.  One app in one tomcat will call the other app in the second tomcat.  Each tomcat is configured with its own set of ports in server.xml.  Each one also has its own security key.  Here is the snippet of server.xml.

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" keystorePass="apple123"   keystoreFile="/usr/myFirstKey"  sslProtocol="TLS" />
    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

When the app in the first tomcat makes a rest call to the second app in the second tomcat with the url "https://localhost:8444/dashboard", I got this error:

> Exception in Sevlet is sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX
>   path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Can someone show me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to use HTTPS to communicate between two internal servers; just use HTTP and avoid all the trouble.

But if you insist on HTTPS, you need tomcat#1 to trust the certificate of tomcat#2 -

Export the certificate of tomcat#2 from its `key store` file

```
> keytool -exportcert -alias <alias> -file <XXX>.cer 
  -keystore <keystore>.jks -storepass <password>
```

Import the certificate to the `trust store` of tomcat#1

```
> keytool -importcert -alias <alias> -file <XXX>.cer 
  -keystore <truststore> -storepass changeit
```

the default `trust store` is `JAVA-HOME/lib/security/cacerts`; it might be better to make a copy of it, and configure tomcat#1 to use the copy.

Comment: Better yet, create a brand-new trust store with your server's certificate, and configure whatever component you are using to connect to use *that* trust store. There's no need to trust the entire world.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz - true. actually, tomcat#2 's keystore can be used as tomecat#1 's truststore.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I make tomcat#1 to trust comcat#2. It works.